# Soft Delete bundle for Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, soft-delete

I've been looking for a good way to implement soft delete in symfony 3. It would appear [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html) exists for Symfony 2 but I have not seen anything similar for Symfony 3.

I wouldn't mind making a bundle for this if one doesn't exist. If it doesn't exist could somebody explain a general approach and what that might look like in Symfony 3 (I am still quite new to Symfony!)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try out [Doctrine2 Behaviors](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors) by KNP Labs if you are using Doctrine ORM. It changes the behaviour for deletion, so that even if you call 
`$em->remove($object);` it is still persistent in your database.
I am using the Translatable/Translation Traits in my Symfony 3.2 App and it is working fine.

Comment: Wow that sounds absolutely perfect! I'll give it a try right now :) many thanks!!!